# Telerik treeView load-on-demand. How can i find and expand some nodes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc

all
I need your help! I'am try to use Telerik TreeView control (asp.net mvc) with Ajax load-on-demand data loading.
On my *.aspx page (before the TreeView will be shown) i need find some top node in TreeView and find and expand some its children nodes. In this I have a problem:

```
how can I do this when the child elements have not yet been loaded?
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to handle the clientside onload/onDataBinding events in javascript.

[Telerik Treeview clientside events](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/treeview/clientsideevents)

Comment: how can i bind onload/ondatabinding events on clientside using jQuery?

Comment: Look at the view tab on the link I posted. There are code examples there.